# Add prefix and suffix to a word in Atom?

Tags: markdown, atom-editor, kramdown

Is there a way to select a word and then have a prefix and suffix added to it with say a short cut key.

I am using Jekyll and Kramdown markdown. I am doing a lot of making single words bold. To do this I have to add `**` before and after each word, e.g. `**hello**`.

The text is generally copied in with no formatting.

So, in Atom I want to be able to double click the word hello and then a shortcut maybe to add `**  **` around it?

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [markdown-writer](https://atom.io/packages/markdown-writer) and then you can bold with `ctrl+b`.